# Issues Formatting Azure Cognitive skill set input correctly for ML integration

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-cognitive-search, azure-machine-learning-service

I am attempting to integrate Azure machine learning with Azure Cognitive Search. I am using a Skill Set and currently the schema for the real-time ML endpoint is this:

```
"Inputs": {
        "WebServiceInput0":
        [
            {

                "CompanyName": "Apple Inc",
            }
        ]
    }
```

When using a debugging session to determine if the skill set setup is correct, I get an error saying that the input data doesn't follow the schema.

This is what the skill set outputs:

```
"Inputs": {
          "WebServiceInput0": {
            "CompanyName": "Apple Inc",
          }
        }
```

I have noticed in the schema that the **WebServiceInput0** property is an array and therefore this is potentially causing the issue.

I am wondering how I could format the input and add "[" to make **WebServiceInput0** an array.

I have tried the Shaper Skill although this wasn't helpful.